# How to convert a varchar to decimal in a SQL Server query?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

In my database I gave `CHARGECODE` and `CHARGECODE_URGENT` columns with a `varchar` datatype and length 15.

However to nap I need that two data become decimals.

Most values ​​are for example (40 or 55). But there are also 44.00 and -450.

So I tried to convert them with CAST and CONVERT.

```
string cmdText = @"SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TEST_URGENT = 'T' THEN CAST(CHARGECODE_URGENT AS decimal) ELSE CAST(CHARGECODE AS decimal) END) AS Somme FROM  JOB_HEADER";
```

I also tried:

```
 string cmdText = @"SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TEST_URGENT = 'T' THEN CONVERT(decimal, CHARGECODE_URGENT) ELSE CONVERT(decimal,CHARGECODE) END) AS Somme FROM  JOB_HEADER";
```

I still get this error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Yet I check if the conversion is possible and it seems so. So I think I have a syntax problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: Why did you use a `varchar` if you want a `decimal` in the first place?

Comment: The rationale for Gordon's answer below is that at least one of your values when tets_urgent=T is not suitable for conversion to decimal. It either has text in it or is "blank"

Comment: @stickybit 
I am intern is not "my database". I use a database produced that I can not edit.

Comment: how clean is the data?

Comment: You have to be sure all values storage in the table are valid, and can be casted, otherwise you get exeptions. Maybe you can show us some data.

Comment: @eripap I checked the 1000 line of the database and you're right the mistake came from me. Even if most of the values ​​are for example (40 or 55) I did not see both 44.00 and -450. I can not convert them to decimal ? Sorry if it's obvious I'm a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TRY_CAST()` or `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TEST_URGENT = 'T'
                THEN TRY_CAST(CHARGECODE_URGENT AS decimal)
                ELSE TRY_CAST(CHARGECODE AS decimal)
           END) AS Somme
FROM JOB_HEADER;
```

To find the bad values, you can do:

```
select CHARGECODE_URGENT
from job_header
where try_cast(CHARGECODE_URGENT as decimal) is null and
      test_urgent = 'T';
```

and:

```
select CHARGECODE
from job_header
where try_cast(CHARGECODE as decimal) is null and
      test_urgent <> 'T';
```

Comment: I get a new error :
'TRY_CAST' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: How can I sum these two queries ?